# Powershell: Upgrading from v.1 to v.3

Tags: powershell

I have a machine with windows server 2008 and has Powershell v.1, I have a few cron jobs executing a few powershell scripts that run on v.1.

My question is: Will any scripts break if I upgrade to version v.3 or is there version v.4 also?

Comment: Part1:Maybe Part2:Yes

Comment: You can still use "-version" for backward compatibility of newer PS versions. For example: powershell -version <version> -file <filePath>

Comment: @kravasb that's only for v3 and higher. v2 *replaced* v1, v3 and higher install alongside the previous versions. So if you have v3 installed, you can use `powershell -version 3` but if you have v2, there is no way to use v1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell 4.0 exists, but it's not supported on Windows Server 2008 (only R2).

Your scripts should work fine, as PS is backwards compatible, ex. PS 1.0 used Snapins instead of modules, and Snapins is still supported in PS 3.0 / 4.0. But as with any upgrade, you need to test it yourself. PS 3.0 + runs on .Net Framework 4, where some APIs may behave differently then they did in earlier versions.

Comment: There were "official" breaking changes, too, perhaps even in each new version (not sure about 4.0). See release notes.

Comment: +1 True. I took a shortcut and covered that with "But as with any upgrade, you need to test it yourself" :)